# (Un)countability of the set of all rational $\infty$-tuples that sum to some strictly positive real number

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Ever real number can be thought of as an infinite sum of rational numbers.

If we denote some strictly positive real number as $x$ and the set of all $\infty$-tuples of strictly positive rational numbers that sum to $x$ as $S_x$, then is $S_x$ countable or uncountable?

To clarify, those $\infty$-tuples of strictly positive rational numbers have the property that if we sum all the members of that $\infty$-tuple then that sum equals $x$ and $S_x$ is the set of all those $\infty$-tuples that have the property that sum of all its elements is $x$.

Of course, the permutations of the same $\infty$-tuple count as one $\infty$-tuple.

Comment: Are you sure you want all permutations of a sequence (i.e., $\infty$-tuple) to count as the same?  If the sum is conditionally convergent then rearranging the terms can make it converge to something different.  If a permutation of a sequence gives another sequence that happens to give the same sum, you might not want to think of those as being "the same".  On the other hand, if the permutation has finite support (i.e., only moves finitely many values) then perhaps you do want to think of the resulting sequences as the same.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I had in mind only strictly positive numbers, I will make and edit.

Answer (score 3):

Let $u_1$ denote the greatest integer $<x$, then define $u_{n+1}$ as $1/k,\,k\in\Bbb N$, with $\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}u_j<x$ and each $k$ being larger than in previous terms. If we choose the least "legal" $k$ at each stage, $\pi=3+\frac18+\frac{1}{61}+\cdots$. But we have $\aleph_0$ options at each stage, giving $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ options overall. What's more, no two contain quite the same rational numbers, so they're not permuted versions of each other.